# Python app processor utilization

Tags: python, multithreading, io

We have following application:
1) python with blocking-io calls
2) application is mostly io-bound
3) application runs multiple threads
4) application is run on single core
Is it going to fully utilise this single core if we choose correct threads amount?
Will be there context switching for threads in case of blocking-io?

Comment: Yes, blocking I/O in the Python standard library releases the GIL and leaves other threads free to run the Python interpreter loop.

Comment: Is there any difference between blocking and non-blocking? Non-blocking (twisted, tornado) allows us to run application without context switching (single thread) which is probably faster?

Comment: Hard to say; cooperative multitasking can be faster than threading, if implemented correctly, because you don't have to worry about locking.